# ESP32s NodeMCU not recognizing SD card breakout: "Card Mount Failed"

Tags: c, arduino, microcontroller, sd-card, esp32

I'm trying to get my NodeMCU ESP32S to connect to an SD card breakout that I have. It is wired up like so:

[image]
I believe these are corrected correctly according to this diagram, which shows the SPI connections on my particular board:

[image]

Unfortunately, when running a simple test of this inside the arduino SDE, I get the following output on the serial monitor:

```
13:37:22.839 -> rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
13:37:22.839 -> configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
13:37:22.839 -> clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
13:37:22.874 -> mode:DIO, clock div:1
13:37:22.874 -> load:0x3fff0018,len:4
13:37:22.874 -> load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
13:37:22.874 -> load:0x40078000,len:8896
13:37:22.874 -> load:0x40080400,len:5816
13:37:22.874 -> entry 0x400806ac
13:37:23.324 -> Card Mount Failed
```

Everything seems to be wired up right, but I was wondering if anyone has any ideas why this might be failing apparently right when the card is attempted to be opened. Here is the code example:

```c
#include "FS.h"
#include "SD.h"
#include "SPI.h"
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(19, INPUT_PULLUP);
  SPI.begin(18, 19, 23);
  if (!SD.begin(5)) {
    Serial.println("Card Mount Failed!");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: Silly questions, but do you have an SD card in the slot, and is it formatted correctly?

Comment: yes, SD card is in the slot and formatted as FAT32

Answer (score 2):

for anybody else that has the same problem with the micro SD module you should connect the VCC pin of micro SD card module to pin Vin of ESP32 not 3.3 V out. The micro-sd card module needs 5V and can't work by 3.3 V

Comment: This should be set as the accepted answer

Comment: This is only applicable for modules that have a built-in regulator

Answer (score 0):

Use VSPI default pins because GPIO12 (HSPI) pin can cause constant rebooting:

```
// define the SD card pins
const int SD_CS_PIN = 5;
const int SD_MOSI_PIN = 23;
const int SD_MISO_PIN = 19;
const int SD_SCK_PIN = 18;

// initialize the SPI bus
SPIClass spi(VSPI);


void setup(){

    Serial.begin(115200);

    spi.begin(SD_SCK_PIN, SD_MISO_PIN, SD_MOSI_PIN, SD_CS_PIN);
    SD.begin(SD_CS_PIN, spi);
    // enter code here

}
```